# How to add a column in between an array in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I've an 2d array named Myarray(1:340,1:50). I want to resize it to 1:340, 1:53. How can I add the column between the array and not at the end of it.

Comment: You would need to create a new array, loop through the first and put the values where you want them.

Comment: Resizing the array will always happen at the end. There is no way to manipulate it from the middle unless you want to transfer the data into other array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have used dynamic arrays, you can resize them.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Myarray() '<~~dynamic array :Dim Myarray(1 to 340, 1 to 50) <~~static array

    ReDim Myarray(1 To 340, 1 To 50)

    Myarray(340, 50) = "a"

    ReDim Preserve Myarray(1 To 340, 1 To 53)

    MsgBox Myarray(340, 50)
    MsgBox UBound(Myarray, 2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry But you can't change the size of the array once created in VBA

Comment: That's not strictly true.

Comment: [`ReDim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/redim-statement)